# XML tag.value not working in SQL 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have a query to append the rows into comma separated values. Please find the Sample query below. This is working in SQL 2012 but not working in SQL 2014.

When I run in SQL 2014 error coming:

> Internal Query Processor Error: The query processor could not produce
>   a query plan. For more information, contact Customer Support Services.

```
SELECT 
    STUFF(TagItem.IDs.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 2, '') AS List,
FROM @tbl1 tbl1
OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT ', ' + [Lookup].Name
    FROM @tbl2   tbl2   
    WHERE tbl1.ID = tbl2.ID 
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
) AS TagItem(IDs)
```

Answer (score 0):

This does the same thing on my SQL 2008 R2 Server.  I can't tell you why it does this, but I can say that if you change to a `CROSS APPLY` the issue goes away.  You do not need an `OUTER APPLY` in this instance because the sub-query with the `FOR XML PATH` will always return a record; it will just be `NULL` if there are no matching records `WHERE tbl1.ID = tbl2.ID`.